# Exception using custom 0.9.6 RPM (and how do I post to the Storm mailing list?)

Tags: apache-storm

We installed a custom RPM built from the 0.9.x branch in an attempt to fix this bug:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-763

But when running on the new installation, we see the below stacktrace.

Any recommendations of how to fix the issue we are seeing, or if/when a stable release of 0.9.6 will be available?

Also, I tried to post this question to the Storm mailing list.

When I send my question as an email to this address: user@storm.apache.org, I get an email back from their mail daemon saying my email could not be delivered.

When I send my question to this address dev@storm.apache.org, I don't get a failed response, but the question never shows up on the mailing list archive?

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-dev/

Comment: You need to subscribe to the list first before you can mail to it. See Storm website on how to subscribe.

Comment: thanks. and then after subscribing I post by sending an email to that address? because i subscribed, confirmed my subscription, and then sent my email. but it still doesn't show as a topic in the archive?

Comment: The address for subscription is different as the mailing list address itself. So after subscribing you mail to dev@ or user@

Comment: Btw. For you current question you should use dev list.